# How to automatically close an Interstitial Ad after specific amount of time?

Tags: java, android, admob

I am programming an app and using an Interstitial Ad Unit (With Google-AdMob).
I want to program it so the ad will automatically close the ad after a specific amount of time.
This is the code that I was talking about:

```
    private void showInterstitial() {
        // Show the ad if it's ready. Otherwise toast and reload the ad.
        if (mInterstitialAd != null && mInterstitialAd.isLoaded()) {
            mInterstitialAd.show();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            //here I need to close the ad
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't close Admob Interstitial ad programmatically. Admob doesn't allow developers to close Interstitial ad programmatically. Only users can close ads by clicking on close button or back button.